# Block email sender

Tags: c#, outlook, office365, vsto, outlook-addin

Is there anyway you can create a code, when you click a button (I've already created this) it will take the selected email and block the sender which will delete the email?

Comment: Are you tryig to add a particcular email address to the blocked senders list in Outlok (rigth click on an email, Junk | Block Sender)?

Comment: i want to be able to automate the process of blocking a sender instead of right click - junk - block sender

Comment: Removed tags from title; grammar.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook Object Model does not expose blocked/safe senders at all.
If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) is an option, it exposes [RDOJunkEmailOptions](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdojunkemailoptions.htm) object (returned from [RDOSession](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm).`JunkEmailOptions`, [RDOAccount](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAccount.htm).`JunkEmailOptions`, [RDOExchangeMailboxStore](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdostore.htm#RDOExchangeMailboxStore).`JunkEmailOptions`), which allow to add blocked senders using `RDOJunkEmailOptions.BlockedSenders.Add`.

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide anything for that. However you can create a VSTO add-in which can handle incoming emails and delete them is the sender belongs to a blocked list. The `NewMailEx` event of the `Application` class is fired when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. You can use the Entry ID returned in the EntryIDCollection array to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/namespace-getitemfromid-method-outlook) method and process the item. Use this method with caution to minimize the impact on Outlook performance. However, depending on the setup on the client computer, after a new message arrives in the Inbox, processes like spam filtering and client rules that move the new message from the Inbox to another folder can occur asynchronously.

See [Walkthrough: Create your first VSTO Add-in for Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-your-first-vsto-add-in-for-outlook) to get started quickly.