# Modify "Blocked email senders" list from JunkFolder in Outlook VSTO

Tags: c#, outlook, registry, vsto, outlook-addin

I am trying to automate the process of Blocking an email address from Outlook (the option is located in Junk Folder context options). I understand that VSTO API does no expose this thing as it is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50954108/block-email-sender). I have been successful in using Outlook Redemption, but unfortunately I cannot use it. Is there any other way (maybe using registry options or something ?)

Here is my code when using Outlook Redemption:

```
RDOSession session = new RDOSession();
session.Logon();
RDOJunkEmailOptions junkOptions = session.JunkEmailOptions;
var senderAddress = mailItem.Sender.Address;
junkOptions.BlockedSenders.Add(senderAddress);
junkOptions.Save();
session.Logoff();
```

Comment: You can use Extended MAPI to read the appropriate profile sections, but MAPi is not accessible in C#.

Comment: BTW, if your code is running inside an addin, tehre is no reason to call RDOSession.Logon - just set the RDOSession.MAPIOBJECT property to Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT  from Outlook.

Comment: could you elaborate on this MAPIOBJECT please ? I have started using Outlook Redemption for a short time and I don't really know all it's tricks

Comment: RDOSession.Logon() above logs to the default profile and internally creates a new MAPI session. There is no reason to do that if your code is running in an addin - in that case, Outlook already has an active session, you can borrow it by setting the RDOSession.MAPIOBJECT property to Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT from Outlook. In that case, also comment out the Logoff call (since the session belongs to Outlook, you should not destroy it).

Comment: thank you for the response. I will try this tomorrow.

Comment: it still asks for user license agreement when I create the new RDOSession(). Is there a way to make Redemption not ask this every time ?

Comment: The dev version always displays the EULA prompt.You would need to purchase the distributable version to get rid of the prompt.